# Android Add fragment within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I'm trying to add a fragment within a subclass of DialogFragment. I have a FrameLayout with an id `pref_container` that I want to replace with a fragment called `settingsFragment`.

The problem is that `fragmentTransaction` can't find `R.id.pref_container`, I don't know if this is because pref_container is only inflated in `onCreateView` rather than being part of the activity?

I am very new to Android programming, so thank you for your time.

```
class QuestionnaireDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        this.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme)

    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questionnaire_layout,container,true)

        val settingsFragment = ExercisesOnlySettingsFragment()
        val ft = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()

        /// **** Here fragmentTransaction can't find R.id.pref_container because it's inflated later and not loaded as part of the activity? ****

        ft?.add(R.id.pref_container, settingsFragment)
        ft?.commit()

        return view
    }


}
```

The runtime error I get is

`No view found for id 0x7f09009c (com.lescadeaux.kegel:id/pref_container) for fragment ExercisesOnlySettingsFragment{4ba4b89 #1 id=0x7f09009c}`

Here is relavent part of my XML for questionnaire_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:id="@+id/questionnaireLayout"
                                             android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- RELAVENT PART -->
            <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/pref_container">
            </FrameLayout>
            <!-- RELAVENT PART -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add questionnaire_layout xml code

Comment: Have you tried using `replace()` instead of `add()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use `getChildFragmentManager()` (or its kotlin equivalent) instead of `getFragmentManager()` you are using - it will work.